# Look up if a file is imported anywhere in a repository

Tags: shell, svg

I have a bunch of unused assets (svgs and pngs) in my repo that I would like to clean up. I have a naive algorithm of looking them up one by one and figuring out if they are referenced in the repo, but I'm looking to write a script that could automate this.

IS there a way to look up if a string of txt is referenced anywhere in the repo from the shell?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question - you can treat the filepath as any other string and use the following command

```
grep <filename> <path> -r
```